# Grails named queries 

Tags: grails, named-query

I started to write a simple named query in Grails, but it says missing method on the domain for the named query. Am I doing something wrong? I referred the documentation and found no problem with the code. Any help?

I just tried the example in the documentation.

```
class Publication {
   String title
   String author
   Date datePublished
   Integer numberOfPages

    static namedQueries = {
       recentPublications { 
          def now = new Date() 
          gt 'datePublished', now - 365 
       }
    }
}
```

invoked the named query like

```
Publication.recentPublications()
```

It was complaining that the method recent publication was missing. I am using grails 1.3.1

Comment: Can you post your domain class?

Comment: Without code, it is almost impossible to answer your question

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
Publication.recentPublications.list()
```

instead of:

```
Publication.recentPlublications()
```